# if $G$ is a group and $[G: G /Z(G)] =4$ prove that $G /Z(G) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a group  and $[G: G /Z(G)] =4$ prove that
$$G /Z(G) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2,$$

where
$$Z(G)=\{z \in G: \forall g \in G, zg=gz \}.$$

Guessing use Lagrange's Theorem. $|G : G/Z(G)|=4$

Somehow $ |G/Z(G)|=4 $ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2 $ by some Theorem that says any group of order 4 is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ but I know there is some stuff is wrong but might be in the right track

Comment: You may want to rethink how you're asking questions.  I've seen (and answered) several of your questions.  It may be good if you could think deeper about the problem - be careful about writing "junk" or random facts; it would be better to be confident that they really relate to your question.  For example, in this question, you wrote down the definition of $Z(G)$ (without using words to say it's the definition) and the stuff below that doesn't really apply to this problem (and some is wrong).  It may be enough to explain your thoughts and plan in words instead of as disconnected facts.

Comment: @MichaelBurr  I know. You make good points. THe argument back is that I use to have half a day to do a problem.   I can just pay for chegg or use the solutions manuals. I know other people do this. I grade for a class and they turn in the same files and I cant give them a zero. I can barely keep track. when I use solutions manual I think its fair for me to get a zero.,  cut me some slack. Idk whats junk and wants not. Maybe there is others ways to prove things.    I am not making you do anything. You dont have to help if u dont want to. I am not forcing you to do anything.

Comment: @michelBurr why has not anyone asked this before? I wonder why. becuase they know it and did it bythemselves?? I think the best for a teacher is to ask fewer questions that are  original and well tought out thats like cheating in away.

Comment: But $G/Z(G)$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more general result that states that $G/Z(G)$ cannot be a cyclic group.

Sketch:
Suppose that $G/Z(G)$ is a cyclic group with generator $aZ(G)$.  Then, every element of $G$ can be written as $a^kz$ where $z\in Z(G)$.

Let $a^{k_1}z_1$ and $a^{k_2}z_2$ be two elements of $G$.  Then the two elements commute because

1. Elements of $Z(G)$ commute with everything in the group.
2. Powers of $a$ commute with other powers of $a$.

Therefore $G$ is abelian and $Z(G)=G$.

Since there are only two groups of order $4$, $\mathbb{Z}/4$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^2$, and $G/Z(G)$ can't be cyclic, this only leaves the other option.